# Best way of using HTML strings in Android strings.xml

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-resources

I can see that there are multiple ways to use Html strings. What is the best way of using HTML Strings in Android strings.xml? I have mentioned 2 ways below: Which one is prefereable and why?

1. Use CDATA

`<string name="test"><![CDATA[Test Message.<br/><br/>Please contact <a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_top">test@test.com</a> for more details.</string>`

2. Use unicode

`<string name="test">Test Message.&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;Please contact &lt;a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_top"&gt;test@test.com&lt;/a&gt; for more details.</string>`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can do like

```
Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.test));
textView.setText(s);
```

and string.xml

```
<string name="test">
    Test Message.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Please contact 
    <a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_top">test@test.com</a> 
    for more details.
</string>
```

Comment: I am not looking for any specific case. Above string is just an example. I need to understand the pros and cons of each approach. On few devices, '<' may replaced with some garbage, so better to use unicode. Is that problem also solves by using CDATA tag?